# How big image can be read and displayed in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with image reading. I want to make sure how big image can be read and displayed in matlab? It is possible to display huge images like (12689,4562,7). If not, how can I check whether this image loaded correctly in matlab?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions here:

1. Is it possible to load a large image from the disk to RAM?
2. Is it possible to show a large image?

The answer to the first question is that it depends on your amount of RAM and operating system. The answer to the second question is that Matlab (or any program) downscales the image before showing, since there aren't that much pixels on the image. So it depends on the internal algorithm, and again, on your amount of RAM.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrey. Ram of my PC is 8 GB, 64 bit operating system. It seems ok. can be read in matlab. So another thing caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The number of MB of RAM required for such an image would be (assuming 8 bits/pixel (`uint8`)):

```
12689*4562*7 / 1e6 = 405.2 MB
```

The number of elements a single matrix can contain in your version of Matlab:

```
[~, numEls] = computer;
```

which is `2.147483647e+09` on my 32-bit R2010b. This is much more than `12689*4562*7`, so in principle, if you have 406GB of unused RAM, you should be able to load the image in its entirety into RAM. And in principle, *displaying* said image will involve some additional RAM (and probably take a **looong** time), but should nevertheless be possible (aside from the fact that displaying an image with 7 colour layers is not very standard AFAIK).